# Reading .vxl file (Ace of Spades)

Tags: java, voxel

I have been busy in the last couple of days designing and coding a voxel for Java.

My ultimate goal is to have a small game with a player who can move around and shoot things in a voxel-based world. Everything has been working great so far - I have gotten the voxel engine to work and to load a map saved in a simple XML format. However, I would like to be able to load .vxl maps from Ace of Spades (I believe it uses Voxlap).

I found [this](http://silverspaceship.com/aosmap/aos_file_format.html) as a manual on how a .vxl is structured. However, how would I go about implementing something similiar in Java, instead of the C++ pseudo-code? I'm not asking for code, just for a direction on how to do something like that.